# javaScript background click color change

Tags: javascript, css, colors, onclick, background-color

i want to   change   multiple color  in  my website .but how ? my webstite body bg color changed good ,but i can't change section background-color .Help me

iam trying to some  javascrip body bg-color change.it worked but i want to change my section bg-color

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood it correct but can you try the code below.

```js
 const btn = document.getElementById('my-btn');
 const section = document.getElementById('my-section');
 const colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];
 const colorIndex = 0;
    
 btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
     const newColorIndex = parseInt((Math.random() * (3 - 1) + 1).toFixed());
     section.style.backgroundColor = colors[newColorIndex - 1];
 });
```

```css
 #my-section {
     height: 300px;
     border: 1px solid #000;
 }
        
 #my-btn {
     margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<button id="my-btn">Click Me</button>
<div id="my-section"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to change background of element with id=outer-section.

HTML:

```
<section id="outer-section">
    <section id="inner-section">
    </section>
</section>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("outer-section").style.background = "red"

// or using parentElement
document.getElementById("inner-section").parentElement.style.background = "red"
```